# How do I include GLES with old GL

Tags: c++, opengl-es

Well, I am very new to graphics programming and I'm not really sure if my assumptions are true about this GLES. But, how do I include it properly.. because I need this `glBlendFuncSeparator()` in my program as a substitute to this `glColorMask()` which I can only found in `GLES/gl2.h`?

And one more.. Can I use GLES functions on PC? because a lot of which I encounter using this is programming in cellphones, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL ES code should not require much work to run on OpenGL, because OpenGL ES is basically a subset of OpenGL.  Any OpenGL ES function you want is also available in OpenGL.

However, if you are programming a Windows desktop application, you have to be wary of the obsolete headers that Microsoft provides.  The OpenGL headers from Microsoft are for OpenGL 1.1, and to give you an idea of how obsolete this is, OpenGL 1.2 was released in 1998.  In order to write modern OpenGL programs on Windows, you'll need newer headers or a way to get pointers to the desired functions.  GLEW ([GLEW home page](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)) is a library which is often used for this purpose.

The functions you list should be available on all OpenGL implementations (except, perhaps, the software OpenGL renderer on Windows).  `glColorMask()` ([man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColorMask.xml)) has been part of OpenGL since version 1.0, and `glBlendFuncSeparate()` ([man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBlendFuncSeparate.xml)) has been part of OpenGL since version 1.4 (you meant "separate", right? "separator" is probably a typo).

There are also ways to create OpenGL ES contexts on desktops if you want to.  It's a bit tricky and platform-specific, but so is creating a normal OpenGL context.

Comment: But why Microsoft don't upgrade its OpenGL? I assume they just want us to use more of their DirectX?hmm... Yes, its a typo because I'm still very not very familiar on other ogl functions. Also why they keep adding extra letters on the GL, why don't they just use numbers, like versions ? Never mind, I know they have the logical purpose why they do that. Many thanks!